# Cookie name [_xyz_/xyz-abc/] is a reserved token

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

I have an application which runs in tomcat. I am able to run the app when i create a war and run it in tomcat which i have it in my downloads folder. However, If I try to add the tomcat in eclipse and try to access it from the browser, I am getting an error "Cookie name is a reserved token". But I am not facing this out of eclipse.

Comment: Getting an error *where*? In a server log? In the browser console? Is there related code you can share? How would someone reproduce it?

Comment: I am getting the error in Server log.

Comment: You really need to volunteer more information if you want answers. Give us actual server output. If this cookie name is reserved, are you using it somewhere, and if so, why?